# Combine two functions in mathematica to get one image with two elements

Tags: plotting, graphics

I am trying combine this two functions into one piece in grid.

```
RegionPlot[x^2+y^2<=1 \[And] y>x,{x,-2,2},{y,-2,2},PlotPoints->15]

Graphics[Disk[{1/2,-1/2}, 1/2]]
```

I tried put Disk[{},] inside first one but it doesn't work.
I would appreciate for any help.

Comment: All: this is almost certainly a duplicate.  Please search and vote to close appropriately if you have time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine the two functions in Show[]:

`Show[RegionPlot[x^2+y^2<=1 \[And] y>x,{x,-2,2},{y,-2,2},PlotPoints->15],Graphics[Disk[{1/2,-1/2}, 1/2]]]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can put it inside `RegionPlot` but you have to use `Epilog` or `Prolog`:

```
RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 <= 1 \[And] y > x, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 PlotPoints -> 15, Epilog -> Disk[{1/2, -1/2}, 1/2]]
```